# yum install apache:asp module?

Tags: apache-2.2, yum

My apache is not installed from source,but by **yum** .

Now I want to add the `apache:asp` module to it,is it still possible with **yum**?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What operating system and version are you running?

Comment: @obfuscurity ,it's centos.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is a CentOS build, you'll have to pull it from CPAN. They have instructions on the Apache:ASP site [here](http://www.apache-asp.org/install.html#Linux%20DSO%20Di0714bb20)

Comment: this looks better than my answer, you can also use `yum search asp` or `yum search <criteria>` to search your repositories for packages that you might want, in the future.

Comment: @cpbills: yep, i hopped on one of my 5.4 test boxen and did that to check :)  the only thing that was there was the mono libraries in the standard repos.

Comment: i don't have yum to play with, but google showed me a potential package, `perl-apache-asp`, it may not be in the main repositories, and may not have been what he wanted in anyway... but... hey...

Comment: Sorry,but what's **CPAN**?

Comment: @wamp: http://www.cpan.org/ ... It's a repository for perl modules.